# Why the specific factor of $2 * 10^{-7}$ is used while defining 1 ampere?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, conventions, si-units, metrology

while defining an ampere through force between two current-carrying wires, I noticed that they considered the force between two wires as $2 \times 10^{-7}$ forming a definition as follows:-
"One ampere of current is expressed as the proportion of current that flows through two incredibly long parallel cables such that the wires remain distanced by 1 m and create an attractive force of $2 \times 10^{-7 }\mathrm{N / m}$ .
why they specifically used $2 \times 10^{-7}\mathrm{N}$?

Comment: Search term: [dyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyne)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the old definition of the ampere. A [new definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_redefinition_of_the_SI_base_units) based on the electron charge was adopted a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with you two parallel long wires the magnetic field due to one at a distance $r$ is $\dfrac {\mu_0 I_1}{2\pi r}$ where $I_1$ is the current and $r$ is the distance from the other wire carrying a current $I_2$.

Thus the force per unit length on the other wire is $\dfrac {\mu_0 I_1I_2}{2\pi r}$ and it was decided to **define** $\mu_0 = 4\pi\times 10{-7} \,\rm H\,m^{-1}$ which then makes the constant term $\dfrac{\mu_0}{2\pi} = 2 \times 10^{-7}$.

The value of $\mu_0$ was chosen such that the [rationalized metre–kilogram–second system (rmks)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_system_of_units) unit of current was equal in size to the ampere in the older [centimetre–gram–second system (cgs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Electromagnetic_units_(EMU)) of units.

The rmks system then evolved into the SI system.

Answer (score 1):

You should know , that 1A was before 1948 defined by the amount of silver deposited in electrolysis  (1,118 mg/s). Than on wanted to  do it with the units of kgs m s, so it had to be the force between two wires. it came out, if one adjusted $\mu_0$ it was just this number for 1m distance, which gave the former magnitude.